# Что не так? Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: Text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard"

Tags: python, telegram, бот

Писала бота для телеги, скопировала со-старого код и чуть переписала, вроде все без ошибок, в точности как на старом, рабочем боте, запускаю - выдает ошибку
Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: can't parse inline keyboard button: Text buttons are unallowed in the inline keyboard"
Вот код

```
import telebot;
import random;
from telebot import types;
bot = telebot.TeleBot('*****************************')
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def get_text_messages(message):


    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Привет")
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='1')
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callabck_data='2')
    button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='3')
    button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='4')
    button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('5', callback_data='5')
    button6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('6', callback_data='6')
    button7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('7', callback_data='7')
    button8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('8', callback_data='8')
    button9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('9', callback_data='9')
    button10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('10', callback_data='10')
    button11 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('11', callback_data='11')
    button12 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('12', callback_data='12')
    button13 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('13', callback_data='13')
    button14 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('14', callback_data='14')
    button15 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('15', callback_data='15')
    button16 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('16', callback_data='16')
    url_button17 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Google', url='https://google.com')
    url_button18 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Yandex', url='https://yandex.ru')
    markup.row(button1, button2)
    markup.row(button3, button4)
    markup.row(button5, button6)
    markup.row(button7, button8)
    markup.row(button9, button10)
    markup.row(button11, button12)
    markup.row(button13, button14)
    markup.row(button15)
    markup.row(button16)
    markup.row(url_button17)
    markup.row(url_button18)
    
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Тыкни", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def query_handler(call):
    bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id)
```

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так

```
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

markup = [[InlineKeyboardButton("1", callback_data='1'),
         InlineKeyboardButton("2", callback_data='2')],
        [InlineKeyboardButton("3", callback_data='3'),
         InlineKeyboardButton("4", callback_data='4')]]

bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f"Тыкни", reply_markup=markup)
```